# 1. Check whether the file exists in the network path/not.; 2. Check the sheet names inside the input file if any mismatches correct it

Tags: python

Hi Have few Questions can any one please help me on these.

1. Check whether the file exists in the network path/not.
2. Check the sheet names inside the input file if any mismatches correct it.
3. Number of columns in each sheet.
4. Check all the column names in each sheet and if any mismatches correct it.

These are questions from my organization can you please help me on this,

I have two folder structure and different excel sheets.

Folder 1: No of Excel files.
Folder 2: No of Excel Files.

Comment: Please edit your tags/question title to properly represent your issue.
1. The tags only say 'python', yet nothing in your question specifically hints towards this being a python issue.
2. Judging from the contents of your question, your problem seems to be MS Excel specific, yet neither the title nor the tags make any mention of it.

Comment: If I assume correctly and your issue is in MS Excel, inspecting the column and sheet names can either be achieved by accessing the Excel API by
1. using Visual basic (hit Alt+F11 to enter the VBA editor)
2. using the win32com.client module in Python

Comment: My request is how can we do in python.

Comment: I'd still recommend to edit the tags and title to mention MS Excel, as this doesn't look like a general python problem, but a python and MS Excel specific issue

Comment: Do you know any way to access MS Excel from Python?

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. This is a place to help people write their own code. Not a "Just ask" for it forum. Please have a try and show some code so we can help. See welcome [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the first question as of now, because the other questions provide too little information on how the problem was initially approached.

Q 1: The built-in os-module provides the necessary functionality to search for a file in a given directory.

the basic concept:

```
import os

parent_dir = "C:\\Users\\YourUserName\\YourFolder" # this is the directory you want to search in
file_name = "some_excel_file.xlsx" # this is the excel file you want to find

path = os.path.join(parent_dir,filename) 
print(os.path.isfile(path)) # Outputs True, if file_name is in parent_dir,
                            # ouputs False, if it is not
```